# How should I implement an ADO connection in an HTTP TIdServerContext thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ado, indy10, httpserver

I've been working on an HTTP server (`TIdHTTPServer`) handling the `OnCommandGet` event. I have just created an inherited object of the `TIdServerContext` and have overridden its constructor and destructor. Now, I'd like to move my Database connection from a prior custom session object into this context thread. The server's `KeepAlive` property is enabled.

The goal is to recycle database connections implemented within each session. Currently every request spawns a new ADO connection, and I'd like to avoid that. I understand `KeepAlive` doesn't necessarily mean an entire login/logout session, but rather just maintaining a constant connection to save resources.

My question is, how should I utilize my inherited `TIdServerContext` object to maintain its own consistent database connection (`TADOConnection`) - which can be used (in the COM rules (`CoInitialize`)) by each request?

I'm assuming that whatever code I put in the `OnCommandGet` event handler runs in the same thread context as the inherited `TIdServerContext` - is this correct? Essentially meaning... Is utilization of both `TIdServerContext.OnRun` and `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` in the same thread and COM safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnCommandGet` does indeed run in the same thread that `TIdServerContext` runs in.

You cannot assign your own `OnRun` handler, because `TIdCustomTCPServer` already uses that event to trigger its `DoExecute()` method, which `TIdHTTPServer` overrides to trigger its `OnCommamd...` events.

If you want to reuse DB object(s) across multiple requests from the same client, you can initialize COM and create the DB object(s) in the `OnConnect` event, and free the DB object(s) and release COM in the `OnDisconnect` event.  However, using these events only helps if the client requests a keepalive on each request, which is not a guarantee.  The `TIdHTTPServer.KeepAlive` property only lets the server honor keepalives if asked for, it does not force clients to ask for them.  If not asked for, every request will trigger its own pair of `OnConnect/OnDisconnect` events.

ADO is COM-based, so it has thread affinity.  Also, COM should be initialized only once per thread.  As such, you are better off initializing COM and creating the DB object(s) when the thread starts, and free the DB object(s) and release COM when the thread ends.  By default, Indy servers use a new thread for each client connection, so by switching to this model, you still benefit from similar behavior as if you use the `OnConnect/OnDisconnect` events.  Whether the client uses keepalives or not, the effect is the same.

However, this model gives you more flexibility, because now you can enable thread pooling in the server (by assigning a `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool` to the `TIdHTTPServer.Scheduler` property) and can then reuse the DB object(s) across multiple client connections that use the same thread over time.

Derive a new class from `TIdThreadWithTask`, override its `BeforeExecute()` method to initialize COM and create the DB object(s), and override its `AfterExecute()` method to free the DB object(s) and release COM.  Assign this class to the scheduler's `ThreadClass` property.

To access the DB object(s) in your `OnCommand...` event, typecast the `AContext.Yarn` property to `TIdYarnOfThread`, then typecast its `Thread` property to your derived class, then you can access its members as needed.

You can still derive a custom `TIdServerContext` class to handle per-client data (Indy does not implement context pooling), and use the DB object(s) on a per-request basis as needed.  Just separate the DB object creation/destruction from the context class.

Comment: + another virtual 1 for the numerous edits :-) This helps me out tremendously.

Comment: many years later but I still find this answer tremendously useful.  Thanks !